# Bash script to tag mp3 files

Tags: bash, metadata, mp3

I would like to edit the metadata of a lot of `.mp3` files. I do not want to do this using a GUI, or any manual one-by-one way. I would like to write a script that adds tags for me. I am in search of a command or way of manually editing the metadata so that I could write something like this:

```sh
for SONG in ./songs/greenday/*
do
  tag --artist="greenday" --album="Dookie" --album-art="./art/greenday/Dookie.jpg" --file $SONG
done
```

I am familiar with tools like:

- Kid3
- EasyTAG
- Mp3tag

But none allow me to do what I want to do in the efficient way I want to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched the debian packages and there is a package called kid3-cli

you can read the manual `man kid3-cli`

Kid3 can write sofisticated ID3v2 and v3 tags that would include the coverart a lot more. This example tags all songs in a folder

```
kid3-cli -c "set title 'I\'ll be there for you'" \
         -c "set albumart 'http://www.example.com/blah.jpg'" \
         -c "set SYLT:'/path/to/lyrics.lrc'" \
         ./songs/greenday/*.mp3
```

remember this is just a example, you must read the man even if it hurts

**And now to something completely different**

If you do not need the cover art you can user mp3tag with can tag straight ID3v1 tags

```
#!/bin/bash

for SONG in ./songs/greenday/*
do
    mp3tag -a "greenday" -l "Dookie" "$SONG"
done
```

... I have tested it, and it works

> ```
> max@linux:~# ./testmp3
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Brett Eldredge_Love Someone.mp3
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Brett Eldredge_Somethin' I'm Good At.mp3
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 48000Hz, 64kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Brett Eldredge_The Long Way.mp3
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Brett Eldredge_The Reason.mp3
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Bring You Back_Don't Ya.mp3
> -------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Illinois_Drunk On Your Love.mp3
> -----------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
>
> Wrote ID3 tag successfully!
> /root/musik/Brett Eldredge- Lose My Mind_Lose My Mind.mp3
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> Artist    : greenday
> Songname  :
> Album     : Dookie                          Year:
> Etcetera  :
> Genre     : (null)
> Info      : Mpeg-1 layer 3 at 44100Hz, 128kb/s (JointStereo)
> ```